# Magento 1.3.2.4 - Advanced search results bug on price sorting

Tags: magento, search, sorting

I've got a small problem that I can't figure out how to fix.

First thing, I CAN'T update magento to a real version who's fixed it. So, I'm looking for an alternative to fix this bug, I can't find out how they fixed it in magento releases, that's why I'm asking here.

Second thing, I'm using Magento 1.3.2.4

When I do a search with the advanced search system and try to sort the restults by price, I've got the following message :

```
You cannot define a correlation name '_price_order_table' more than once
```

I already found some potential answer on Stackoverflow and some other website, like this one : [Magento - using the catalog/product_list block more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791656/magento-using-the-catalog-product-list-block-more-than-once)

But it's not really my case. I don't have a duplicate block in my layout xml files.

Would any of you have any idea of why I've got this error message ? It seems to be a duplicate use of a "left join" on the same table with the same alias, but how can I find where ?

Thank you so much to anyone who read this until the end and especially to the ones who will try to help me and answer me ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Anyway ... I spent too much time on this question to search the perfect solution and debug magento.

I ended in commenting /lib/Zend/db/Select.php on line 760 where the exception was thrown. The sorting works anyway, even with an exception thrown.

Sample of this file and with the line commented.

```
    if (!empty($correlationName)) {
            if (array_key_exists($correlationName, $this->_parts[self::FROM])) {
                /**
                 * @see Zend_Db_Select_Exception
                 */
                #require_once 'Zend/Db/Select/Exception.php';
                //throw new Zend_Db_Select_Exception("You cannot define a correlation name '$correlationName' more than once");
            }
```

I saw the suggestion somewhere on the web when I started to search for this issue some hours ago. Anyway, it's always the same thing : when I get to ask for help, I give up on great fixes and finally accept a workaround.

Hope this may help someone someday and if anyone figure out any other solution, please share ! ;-)